# Maze Game few small problems

Tags: c#

Code updated now, only two problems left until I'm happy to feel I've completed it.

When the player hits a wall the counter goes down at 2 lifes per hit.

When the game starts the sound I have(beep.wav) which should only sound when the player hits a wall, is sounding each time I begin the game and the sound which should play throughout the game(onestop.wav) isn't playing at all.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form       
{
            // This SoundPlayer plays a song when the game begins.
    System.Media.SoundPlayer onestop = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\kC\Favorites\Desktop\Kev stuff\Projects\MazeGame\onestop.wav");

    // This SoundPlayer plays a sound whenever the player hits a wall.
    System.Media.SoundPlayer beepSound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\kC\Favorites\Desktop\Kev stuff\Projects\MazeGame\beep.wav");

    // This SoundPlayer plays a sound when the player finishes the game.
    System.Media.SoundPlayer clapSound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\kC\Favorites\Desktop\Kev stuff\Projects\MazeGame\winningApplause.wav");


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = (1000) * (1);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        begin();

    }

    private void begin()
    {
        onestop.Play();
        livesTextBox.Text = lives.ToString();
        Point startingPoint = panel1.Location;
        startingPoint.Offset(10, 10);
        Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint);
    }

    int lives = 5;

    private void MoveToStart()
    {

        if ( lives > 0)
        {
            lives--;
        }
        if (lives == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Lose!!");
            Close();
        }

        else if (lives < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Lose!!");
            Close();
        }
    }

    private void wall_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the mouse pointer hits a wall or enters the panel,
        // call the MoveToStart() method.
        beepSound.Play();
        MoveToStart();

        lives--;
        livesTextBox.Text = lives.ToString();
    }

    private void finishLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Play a sound, show a congratulatory MessageBox, then close the form.
        clapSound.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You've beaten the maze!");
        Close();
    }

    int gameElapsed = 0;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gameElapsed++;
        textBox1.Text = "" + gameElapsed.ToString();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the code very clearly, but I'll try and help.

Not sure about your sound issues. But: to 'call in your timer', I presume you want to put a number in the text box? You are half-way there. The `Timer` object simply calls the tick event every second, so you need to do the displaying part.

place the text box on your form, assume it is called `textBox1`.

put before the `begin()` method:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
```

Put inside the `begin()` method

```
stopWatch.Start();
```

inside the `timer1_Tick` method:

```
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
```

for your 'lives' bit, you'll need to put, before `begin()` method,

```
int lives = 0;
```

inside the `begin()`, put

```
int lives = 5;
livesTextBox.Text = lives.toString();
```

and inside `wall_MouseEnter()`, put

```
lives--;
livesTextBox.Text = lives.toString();
```

(assuming you have drawn a `livesTextBox` on your form)

Comment: Thank for you for the help, I've progressed a bit on the maze now and I've updated the code, still a few minor problems;/

Answer (score 1):

Just Create a Timer on your form with interval 1000 and make it enable and then define game_elpased as integer as private field in the class and in timer_tick write :

```
void Timer1_Tick(object Sender,EventArgs e)
{
  game_elapsed++;
  textBox1.Text = "Elapsed Seconds : " + game_elapsed.ToString();
}
```

For the live times , You need to control the public variable like lives, when the player fails :

```
if(fails && lives>0){
  lives--;
}
else if (lives<0)
{
  MessageBox.Show("You are a looser ...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, got the timer and lives working, just the lives seem to be going down two per hit now for some reason;s I've edited my post now with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The lives can be a property of the player class.

```
public class Player
{
    int lives = 5;

    public bool Kill()
    {
        this.lives--;
        return this.lives <= 0;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Player player = new Player();

        // do stuff

        // Check whether the player needs to die
        if ("player fails".Contains("fail"))
        {
            if (player.Kill())
            {
                // restart level.
            }
            else
            {
                // Game over.
            }
        }
    }
}
```